# How to understand about instances of the same class cause deadlock issue in C++ Concurrency in Action?

Tags: c++, multithreading, deadlock

I am reading [C++ Concurrency in Action](https://www.cplusplusconcurrencyinaction.com/errata.html), and come across the following statements which describe `deadlock` (page 47 ~ 48):

> The common advice for avoiding deadlock is to always lock the two mutexes in the same order: if you always lock mutex A before mutex B, then you’ll never deadlock. Sometimes this is straightforward, because the mutexes are serving different purposes, but other times it’s not so simple, such as when the mutexes are each protecting a separate instance of the same class. Consider, for example, an operation that exchanges data between two instances of the same class; in order to ensure that the data is exchanged correctly, without being affected by concurrent modifications, the mutexes on both instances must be locked. However, if a fixed order is chosen (for example, the mutex for the instance supplied as the first parameter, then the mutex for the instance supplied as the second parameter), this can backfire: all it takes is for two threads to try to exchange data between the same two instances with the parameters swapped, and you have deadlock!

I am very confused about the meaning of following part:

> However, if a fixed order is chosen (for example, the mutex for the instance supplied as the first parameter, then the mutex for the instance supplied as the second parameter), this can backfire: all it takes is for two threads to try to exchange data between the same two instances with the parameters swapped, and you have deadlock!

In previous, it refers "`an operation`", then it mentions "`two threads to try to exchange data`". What is the actual scenario the author wants to express?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This refers to a situation like this:

You have a function

```
void foo(bar& a, bar& b) {
    lock_guard<mutex> lock1(a.mutex);
    ...
    lock_guard<mutex> lock2(b.mutex);
}
```

which, at first glance, seems to follow the advice of always locking the mutexes in the same order.

But if you have

```
bar a, b;
```

`foo` could be called as

```
foo(a, b);
```

in one thread, and as

```
foo(b, a);
```

in another. Then, you have a deadlock.

Answer (score 2):

> In previous, it refers "an operation", then it mentions "two threads to try to exchange data"

You missed the end of the sentence! It says "two threads to try to exchange data **between the same two instances**". It's not talking about exchanging data between the threads, it's talking about one thread exchanging data between two instances of a type, and another thread exchanging data between the same two instances.

Answer (score 0):

Swap operation is commutative so you do not have a guarantee that algorithms will perform this operation with same order of arguments. So if there is object `a` and `b`, One thread can do `Swap(a, b)` and the other `Swap(b, a)` and end result locks are acquiesced in different order.

If timing is bad this will lead to dead lock.

Note that this can be even more compels three objects and three threads doing: `Swap(a, b)`, `Swap(b, c)`, `Swap(c, a)`. Here locking first argument than second argument can also lead to a dead lock.